# Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/like/4"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Routing Errorを解決したいです。`No route matches [POST] "/like/4"`とさらに表示されました。POSTが合わないということですよね？

routes.rbには下記のように記述しました。

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update,:like]
  resources :notes, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy,:like]

  get'/top' => 'home#top'

  get'/connection' => 'home#connection'
  get'/notes/new' => 'notes#new'
  post'/notes' =>'notes#create'
  get'/notes' =>'notes#index'
  patch'/notes/:id' =>"notes#update",as:'update_note'
  delete'/notes/:id' =>"notes#destroy",as:'destroy_note'

  post '/like/notes/:id' => 'likes#like', as: 'like'          # ←←
  delete '/unlike/notes/:id' => 'likes#unlike', as: 'unlike'

  root 'home#top'
  get'/about' => 'home#about'
end
```

`←←`で示したところにpost のコードを記載し、rake routesを確認したところ、

```
like_path    POST    /like/notes/:id(.:format)    likes#like 
unlike_path    DELETE    /unlike/notes/:id(.:format)    likes#unlike
```

のようになっており、post と記載すべきなのになぜエラーが出るのか？と思いました。 
どのように記述すべきなのでしょうか？ 
お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「どのように記述すべきなのでしょうか？」については的確な回答が出ていますからこちらの部分。
*POSTが合わないということですよね？*
`No route matches [POST] "/like/4"`は「`[POST] "/like/4"`にマッチするようなルートが存在しない」と言う意味です。POSTだけがダメと言っているのではありません。

Answer (score 0):

routesに`post '/like/notes/:id'`で指定しているのですが、エラーに`/like/4`でアクセスしようとしていると書いてあります。
`post '/like/notes/:id'`を`post '/like/:id'`に変えるか、または`/like/4`でアクセスしようとしているコードを変えるかのどちらかで解決できます。